# Oracle Apex - allowing users to enter duration in hours, min & days

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

On Oracle apex - I would like to have a column where my users can enter the duration of the task taken, the task can take anytime between 5 min to couple of days. What is the best way to allow users to enter the value, so that I can add that to the other column later.
Currently I mandated that all users should enter the value in the column in hours, however for the tasks which are less than an hour, users are finding it difficult to convert min to hours.

Then I have a trigger to calculate the end time based on the duration the users enter.
:NEW.END_DATE := :NEW.START_DATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL(:NEW.DURATION01, 'HOUR');

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have interactive grid, I created 3 columns, day, hour and minutes. User can enter in the column and I calculate the total in hours

```
:COLTOTAL := nvl(:COL_DAY,0) * 24 + nvl(:COL_HOURS,0) + (nvl(:COL_MINS,0) / 60);
```

In your case you can,

```
:P1_END_DATE := :P1_START_DATE + numtodsinterval(nvl(:P1_DAY,0) * 24 + nvl(:P1_HOUR,0) + (nvl(:P1_MIN,0) / 60),'HOUR')
```